# Is it possible to run a game on my Ubuntu desktop (that has a powerful GPU), but control it from an Ubuntu laptop (with an integrated GPU)?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, remote-desktop, gpu

I have a desktop machine with a very powerful GPU that can run modern games, but I prefer using my portable notebook which has a great keyboard and trackpad. Is it possible to run the game on my desktop, but display it on my laptop's screen and control it with my laptop's keyboard, mouse and microphone? Both machines have Ubuntu installed.

Comment: I only tried on Windows, but Steam Remote Play might be worth looking into

Comment: The desktop has Ubuntu though. If I install Windows in a VM and run the games there, will those cloud gaming software work normally?

Comment: If I look at the FAQ Steam Remote Play is at least supposed to work on Linux

Answer (score 2):

If both are using Ubuntu, you're in luck—you don't have to install any additional software—all of the remote capabilities are built in, you just need to change some settings.

### Set Static IP Addresses (Recommended)

Before you do anything, go into your router settings and setting a dedicated IP address for each device, that way you don't have to do an IP lookup every time you try to connect.

### Setup Host Computer

1. Open a terminal on the computer running the game and type: `vino-preferences`. This is also available on the dashboard as `Desktop Sharing`. Make the following selections:

   - `Allow other users to view your desktop`
   - `Allow other users to control your desktop`
   - `Require the user to enter this password`
2. Set a strong password, in case a bad actor gains access to your network.
3. Close preferences.

### Setup Client Computer

1. On the desktop that you're controlling the game from, open terminal and type: `remmina` or select `Remmina Remote Desktop Client` from the dashboard.
2. Press `Ctrl`+`N` to create a new connection.
3. Under the 'Server' field, enter the IP address of the host computer (the benefit of setting static IP).

   - You can save this connection to make future remote access easier.
4. Press 'Connect'

### Controlling Host Computer

On the client computer you're playing from you will be asked for the password you set up on the host computer. If the credentials match, you should have full keyboard and mouse control over the second computer.

> **NOTE:** If the computers are not on the same network, you'll need to setup port forwarding. That is a little more in depth so just stick to the same network for now.
> Also note that with any generic VNC/RDP type connection you will likely not have access to macros/keybindings that have been set up.

### Software Alternative

If you experience any lag or if the machine hosting the game is primarily used for only this purpose I would highly suggest you check out SteamOS, a Debian-based distribution that is tailored specifically for gaming and home-theatre/network purposes. It may be to your benefit to switch to this distribution as it is free and designed for gaming.

https://store.steampowered.com/steamos/

If you are familiar with PS4 Remote play, the protocols used are compatible, so you can also connect to a console with the OS as well. If you don't have any experience with SteamOS or PS4 Remote Play, it is as smooth as playing on the host device regardless of where you're connecting from, as long as your connection is good. A SteamOS desktop can stream even to a phone or netbook with hardly a hiccup in performance.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Ubuntu, but the terms used ""Desktop sharing", "Remote Desktop" imply that this is a standard Remote Desktop solution like RDP, teamviewer, etc, which tend to be quite unsuitable for sharing content like videos/games. Can you confirm your suggestion actually works for games, at decent frame rates and low latency?

Comment: @Peter It utilizes VNC or RDP. If you're on the same network there should be little issue. I have used this Remote desktop for low latency games with minimal issues going from Ubuntu2Ubuntu & Windows2Ubuntu. Some things like keybindings may be lost using this route. Updating answer with another suggestion that's geared towards games as well.